# Poetry can't find dependencies on installation

Tags: python, django, macos, python-poetry

I'm trying to run a Django project. The project has the files `poetry.lock` and `pyproject.toml` and it runs on other computers, but I can't install it on my computer ([macOS v12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey)).

On my computer with the newly created virtual environment (venv), when I run those commands:

```
python3.10 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
poetry install
```

I receive the message:

> No dependencies to install or update.

When I run the `poetry show` command, several libraries are listed. But when I run `python manage.py runserver`, Python doesn't find any libraries.

(I can run older Python projects on my computer.)

Comment: You eally must provide as much details as possible for questions like these, show the input/output from your shell (as formatted text) etc.  Show the actual outputs of the commands you are descrbing.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just found a solution: running `poetry shell` before `poetry install`